# Sequences combined with limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let ${a_n} {b_n} {c_n}$ be sequences such that

1. $a_n+b_n+c_n=2n+1$,
2. $a_n \cdot b_n+b_n \cdot c_n+c_n \cdot a_n=2n-1$,
3. $a_n \cdot b_n \cdot c_n=-1$,
4. $a_n<b_n<c_n$.

Then find the value of $na_n$ as $n$ tend to infinity.

Comment: Can I consider the three sequences to be the roots of a cubic equation

Answer (score 1):

Studying the equations you have:

From (i), $b_n+c_n=(2n+1)-a_n$

From (iii), $b_n\cdot c_n=\dfrac{-1}{a_n}$

So, replacing in (ii), we have:

\begin{align*}
a_n\cdot b_n + b_n\cdot c_n + c_n\cdot a_n &=2n-1\\
a_n(b_n+c_n)+(c_n\cdot b_n)&=2n-1\\
a_n((2n+1)-a_n)-\frac{1}{a_n}&=2n-1\\
a_n^2((2n+1)-a_n)-1&=(2n-1)a_n\\
-a_n^3+(2n+1)a_n^2-(2n-1)a_n-1&=0
\end{align*}

Obtaining: $$a_n^3-(2n+1)a_n^2+(2n-1)a_n+1=0.$$ However, by the symmetry of the equations (i),(ii) and (iii), with respect to $a_n,b_n,c_n$, it can be said $a_n,b_n,c_n$ are the three solutions of the equation

$$x^3-(2n+1)x^2+(2n-1)x+1=0$$

Notice that $x=1$ is a solution of the equation, so by factoring $(x-1)$ we obtain

$$(x-1)(x^2-2n x-1)=0$$

From which the other solutions are

$$x=\dfrac{-2n-n\sqrt{4n^2+4}}{2}, \hspace{1cm}x=\dfrac{-2n+n\sqrt{4n^2+4}}{2}$$

Since $a_n<b_n<c_n$, then $a_n$ is the smallest of these solutions, that is,

$$a_n=\dfrac{-2n-n\sqrt{4n^2+4}}{2}$$
and the sequence $n\cdot a_n=\dfrac{-2n^2-n^2\sqrt{4n^2+4}}{2}$ diverges (the limit is $-\infty$).